# Inequalities for $\mathcal C^1$ functions satisfying $f^\prime(x) \leq af(x)+b$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, exponential-function

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a class $C^1$ function which vanishes in $0$ and which satisfies:
$$\forall x \geq 0,\quad  f'(x) \leq af(x)+b \quad [a > 0, b \geqslant 0] $$
We try to show that:
$$\forall x \geq 0, \quad f(x) \leq {b \frac{e^{ax}-1}{a}}$$ and $$f'(x) \leq be^{ax}$$
Could you direct me to the demo please? I don't see how to start ...
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x) = e^{-ax}f(x)$. Then $g^\prime(x) = e^{-ax}\left(f^\prime(x)-af(x)\right)$ and therefore for all $x \ge 0$

$$g^\prime(x) \le b e^{-ax}.$$

You then get

$$g(x)=\int_0^x g^\prime(t) \ dt \le \int_0^x b e^{-at} \ dt = b\frac{1- e^{-ax}}{a}$$ and the first inequality by replacing $g(x) = e^{-ax}f(x)$.

Now

$$e^{-ax}f^\prime(x) = g^\prime(x) + a e^{-ax}f(x) \le b e^{-ax}+b\left(1-e^{-ax}\right) = b$$ which enables to conclude to the second requested inequality.

Comment: Mmm, some thing must escape me... The second inequality involves the derivative of `f`, not `g`, and the power of exponential is `+ax`.

Comment: I made a mistake that is now corrected.